# jquery.gridster.min.js giving error for delay function in resizable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, min, gridster

```
stop: $.proxy(function (event, ui) {
                delay($.proxy(function () {
                    this.on_stop_resize(event, ui);
                }, this), 120);
            }, this),
```

This delay function is giving error as **Uncaught TypeError : delay is not a function.**

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. What is `delay` supposed to be?

Comment: delay is the function name  which is called from jquery.gridster.min.js file from resizable function.